# How to create git hook in Swift script to prevent console.log() lines?

Tags: swift, githooks

I would put together a Swift script, that prevent nasty `console.log()` JavaScript lines to commit.

All I reached it to make a Hello World in Swift script.

```
#!/usr/bin/swift
print("Hello world")
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use one of the bajillion JS linting tools which already have rules for this? ESLint was the big one last I checked

Comment: I would see the possibility of Swift script use in git hooks.